# How to extract the string part from a byte array?

Tags: python, numpy, byte, pickle

I converted a numpy array into a byte array using pickle, the code snippet is as follows:

```
bytes_array = pickle.dumps(np.array([1,2,3]))
```

the corresponding result is

```
b'\x04\x95\xa0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x15numpy.core.multiarray\x94\x8c\x0c_reconstruct\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x05numpy\x94\x8c\x07ndarray\x94\x93\x94K\x00\x85\x94C\x01b\x94\x87\x94R\x94(K\x01K\x03\x85\x94h\x03\x8c\x05dtype\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x02i8\x94\x89\x88\x87\x94R\x94(K\x03\x8c\x01<\x94NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00t\x94b\x89C\x18\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94t\x94b.'
```

Since I only need the string part from the previous bytes array, '\x04....', is there any way to achieve that? I tried the following with no luck.

```
str(bytes_array)[1:]
```

Comment: What is the problem with the last snippet?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the string part"? Are you asking how to encode a bytes object as a string of escape sequences, like a bytes literal? If you just need to map bytes to a printable string representation and back, you might want to look into using a [hexadecimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) or [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) representation instead

Comment: @MichaelButscher If I assign a variable x = '\x04....' and then make a comparison to str(bytes_array)[1:], they are not equal. print(x) will give me something like `'numpy.core.multiarray
                      _reconstructnumpyndarrayK
CbR(KK
hdtypei8R(K<NNNJÿÿÿÿJÿÿÿÿKtbCtb.'`

Comment: The `b` is not part of the string. It is an indicator that the object type is a `bytes` string object and not a `str` (Unicode) string object.

Comment: Seems like an [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: @Brian I tried with base64 but it could't preserve the shape of multidimensional array, pickle seemed to work the best, the reason I only need the string part is because I can then encode it with ```new_s = string_part.encode('latin-1')``` and then decode it with ```pickle.loads(new_s))``` to recover the original numpy array.

Comment: @LinxingYao "x" would then be a string of unicode characters which are converted byte values. If you really want that (but I doubt it) you can use `str(bytes_array, encoding='latin-1')` to get it.

Comment: What you have now is the *result* of `.encode('latin1')` so you don’t need the `str`

Comment: @MichaelButscher Your solution worked! Is it possible to assign environmental variables to this value ``` 'numpy.core.multiarray                       _reconstructnumpyndarrayK CbR(KK hdtypei8R(K<NNNJÿÿÿÿJÿÿÿÿKtbCtb.'```? Or any suggestion for the transformation of numpy array so that it can be set as environmental variables.

Comment: Why do you need encoding or unicode?  `loads` works fine with the bytearray. 
 `pickle_loads(bytes_array)`

Comment: @hpaulj It works fine except I need to assign this byte array to an environment variable, any suggestion to work around this problem?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "environment variable".  Where?  Are you talking about a (global) variable in your script?  Or a file that you can load?  Or some string in the `os.environ` (or other OS environment).   Don't confuse a numpy array, it's `dumps` bytestring representation, and a unicode string derived from that (and I could add the `npy` file created with `np.save`).